# what's a proper or simple way for this control flow instead of try catch?

Tags: f#

I cannot find any simple (compared to the `try catch` method, which is rather straightforward) way to do this:

```
try
    Some (line.Split delimiter |> Array.map Int32.Parse)
with
    |_ -> None
```

A bad (call `Parse` twice) approach is like this:

```
let array = line.Split delimiter
let parseSucceed =
    array |> Array.exist (Int32.TryParse >> fst >> not)
          |> not
if parseSucceed then Some (array |> Array.map Int32.Parse) else None
```

Is there any standard way of doing such tasks? Do I have to write up a recursive function to handle this?

What if the input is not an array but a stream/sequence?

#### Update:

@Daniel's method is great.

```
module Seq =
    let tryCatch myFun (x: seq<_>) =
        let rec loop acc (e: IEnumerator<_>) =
            if e.MoveNext() then
                match myFun e.Current with
                | Some v -> loop (v::acc) e
                | None   -> (false, acc |> List.rev |> List.toSeq)
            else
                (true, acc |> List.rev |> List.toSeq)
        use e = x.GetEnumerator()
        loop [] e

let parse x =
    printf "%d " x // log when the function is called.
    if x > 3 then None else Some x

let tt myFun x =
    let y = Seq.tryCatch myFun x
    if fst y then
        printfn "yes %A" (y |> snd |> Seq.toArray)
    else
        printfn "no %A" (y |> snd |> Seq.toArray)

tt parse [| 0;2;1;2;4;1;2 |]
tt parse [| 0;2;1;2 |]

> 
0 2 1 2 4 no [|0; 2; 1; 2|]  // parse is called minimum number of times
0 2 1 2 yes [|0; 2; 1; 2|]
```

Comment: I made a few tweaks to the recursive function which speed it up and simplify it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
let fields = line.Split(delimiter) 
let parsedFields = 
  fields
    |> Seq.map Int32.TryParse
    |> Seq.takeWhile fst
    |> Seq.map snd
    |> Seq.toArray
if parsedFields.Length = fields.Length 
then Some parsedFields
else None
```

Or, if you want something a bit more reusable:

```
module Seq =
  let tryMap f (s: seq<_>) =
    use e = s.GetEnumerator()
    let res = ResizeArray()
    let rec loop() =
      if e.MoveNext() then
        match f e.Current with
        | Some x -> res.Add(x); loop()
        | None -> None
      else Some(seq res)
    loop()

type System.Int32 with
  static member tryParse s =
    match Int32.TryParse(s) with
    | true, i -> Some i
    | _ -> None

//Usage
line.Split(delimiter) |> Seq.tryMap Int32.tryParse
```

Comment: What if the input line.Split(delimiter) is not an array but a stream/sequence?

Comment: I changed the recursive function to use `seq` instead of `array`. If you prefer the pipelined approach, it would be easiest to convert the sequence to an array beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is `'a option array` and you want a `'a array option` where any `None` causes the entire value to be `None`. You could define a function like this:

```
let lift a = 
         Array.foldBack 
                    (fun curr state -> Option.bind 
                                              (fun l -> Option.map (fun c -> c :: l) curr) state) a (Some []) 
         |> Option.map List.toArray;;
```

Usage:

```
lift [| (Some 10); (Some 12); (None); |]
```

> val it : int [] option = None

```
lift [| (Some 10); (Some 12); |]
```

> val it : int [] option = Some [|10; 12|]

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
let optInt32 str =
    match Int32.TryParse str with
    | false, _ ->
        None
    | true, value ->
        Some value


let tryParseDelimited (line : string) (delimiter : char) =
    let pieces = line.Split delimiter
    let parsedPieces = Array.choose optInt32 pieces
    if pieces.Length = parsedPieces.Length then
        Some parsedPieces
    else
        None
```

Comment: it doesn't stop immediately after a fail parse.

Answer (score 1):

If you need working with infinite sequences or streams, it is better to split the big function into several smaller ones, which you can combine when needed:

```
let split delimiters (line: String) =
    line.Split delimiters
    |> Array.toSeq
let parse =
    Seq.map
        (fun x ->
            let (success, value) = Int32.TryParse x
            if success then Some value else None
        )
let isParseSucceed vals =
    vals
    |> Seq.forall Option.isSome
    |> fun b -> if b then Some (vals |> Seq.choose id) else None
```

Note I have intentionally made everything to be `Seq` to support infinite sequences.
Also, `isParseSucceed` traverses the sequence twice, but an alternative is traversing once **and** unwrapping an `Option` (which may become useless if a single `None` value is found), which looks more expensive.

```
// Usage
let x1 = 
    "5,20,42,10"
    |> split [| ',' |]
    |> parse
    |> isParseSucceed
x1 |> printf "%A\n"
// output: Some (seq [5; 20; 42; 10])

let x2 = 
    "5,20,42,foobar,10"
    |> split [| ',' |]
    |> parse
    |> isParseSucceed
x2 |> printf "%A\n"
// output: null

// making an infinite sequence
// with all values are proper Int32's in a string form
// but the 5th value is "FOOBAR"
// We are not using `split` as it is not needed here
let x3 = 
    Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> if(i=5) then "FOOBAR" else i.ToString())
    |> parse
    |> isParseSucceed
x3 |> printf "%A\n"
// output: null

// the following will obviously hang
let x4 = 
    Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i.ToString())
    |> parse
    |> isParseSucceed
x4 |> printf "%A\n"
```

Comment: _"Note I have intentionally made everything to be Seq to support infinite sequences."_ How could this function possibly be made to support infinite sequences? It returns `Some` only if every element can be parsed.

Comment: @Daniel It does support infinite sequences, as demonstrated in examples `x3` and `x4`.

Comment: I guess our concepts of "support" differ. Hanging, in my mind, is never by design.

Comment: @Daniel Correct. But the OP deliberately asked for support of streams/sequences that may be naturally infinite. In real world, you can't do anything with the infinite sequence, if you need processing **all** elements. At best, you can stop at a certain threshold, is there another option?

Comment: No. There's not. It's sensible to operate on `seq`s, but I was merely taking issue with your assertion that it supports infinite sequences. The function answers the question "can every element be parsed?" which can be answered for all *but* infinite sequences.

Comment: @Daniel It *does* support those infinite sequences having non-parseable value at a finite index. Other infinite sequences are *impossible* to support. Hence, it *does not* support everything that is impossible to support. In order to avoid hanging (but still not improving what the code *supports*), some threshold has to be added into a code. Is it correct?

Comment: I concede your point. I suppose `Seq.length` could be said to support infinite sequences in the same way.

Comment: how to make it so that it transverses once only?